# Improving model when Coefficient of Determination (R²)is inconsistent

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

Many examples in the literature state that the value of the coefficient of determination (R²) is a value between 0 and 1, but some cases in my regression model yielded negative results. While researching on the StackOverflow community and also reading the Sklearn library documentation, I found some information indicating that R² can indeed be a negative number when the model performs arbitrarily worse. This is the case with this example where I obtained an R² of **-2.65**:

[image]

```
def calculate_r2(y_true, y_pred):
    y_mean = np.mean(y_true)
    sse = np.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2)
    sst = np.sum((y_true - y_mean)**2)
    r2 = 1 - (sse / sst)
    return r2

y_true = np.array([47, 40, 42, 43, 43, 34, 50, 47, 41, 34, 44, 48, 41, 35])
y_pred = np.array([42, 33, 51, 60, 45, 44, 51, 47, 34, 24, 53, 28, 35, 40])

r2 = calculate_r2(y_true, y_pred)

print("R²:", r2)
```

However, I found another formula that can also be used to calculate R² and decided to test it. Using this alternative formula, the negative results were eliminated, but there were some cases where R² exceeded 1. In this particular case, it was **4.02**:

[image]

```
def calculate_r2(y_true, y_pred):
    y_mean = np.mean(y_true)
    sse = np.sum((y_pred - y_mean)**2)
    sst = np.sum((y_true - y_mean)**2)
    r2 = sse / sst
    return r2

y_true = np.array([47, 40, 42, 43, 43, 34, 50, 47, 41, 34, 44, 48, 41, 35])
y_pred = np.array([42, 33, 51, 60, 45, 44, 51, 47, 34, 24, 53, 28, 35, 40])

r2 = calculate_r2(y_true, y_pred)

print("R²:", r2)
```

How is this possible? I believe that among the two formulas, the one that is widely accepted and used is the first one, which returned a negative value. From my understanding, negative values of R² indicate that the model is not only inadequate but also predicting poorly. Is there anything I can do to improve this result?

**# EDIT 1**

I have a database with 71 records. Several algorithms were employed in the implementation of regression models. The specific result I provided in the example was obtained using LinearRegression with the complete and normalized dataset, with 80% of the data for training and 20% for testing. In some cases (not the case in the example above), I performed data preprocessing using Pearson Correlation (0.98) and PCA (0.99), but I still encountered some instances of negative R² values.

Comment: *"From my understanding, negative values of R² indicate that the model is not only inadequate but also predicting poorly. Is there anything I can do to improve this result?"* Can you show what your model is? Right now, the question doesn't give any details of it at all, so it's not really possible to suggest improvements.

Comment: *"However, I found another formula that can also be used to calculate R² and decided to test it."* Note that this second formula is not valid for all models. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_explained_variance and note the stipulation **"When this relation** [i.e. that SSres + SSreg = SStot)] **does hold..."** It's OK for a simple linear regression, not necessarily for more complex models.

Comment: Hello @slothrop! I added more info about my model, please check "#Edit 1" section. Thank you in advance

Comment: Right. Assuming there's no bug (show your code if you like), it sounds like overfitting and/or the training set not being representative of the test set. (Those two things are in some sense the same type of issue...)